# Angular 2: Passing Async Data to Routes?

Tags: angular, angular2-routing

I have routing with child and I need to pass date which parent get from http request to child route. I tried to use service to sharing data but i want only want only one request.

It's my routes:

```
const routes: Routes = [
    {
        path: 'page/:category',
        component: PageComponent,
        children: [
            {
                path: ''
            },
            {
                path: '/:id',
                component: PageDetailComponent
            }
        ]
    }
];
```

My second question is how to handle route with optional parameters (without reloading component)

```
http://example.com/route
```

same as

```
http://example.com/route/param
```

Comment: Use resolve from https://angular.io/docs/ts/latest/guide/router.html#!#guards

Comment: @GünterZöchbauer thanks a lot, works perfectly!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Solution was route data resolve, because route children have access to their parents data.

Comment: Can you post example code? This sounds like a neat answer.